# close different browser tabs from one application

Tags: javascript, json, cookies, local-storage, window

I have 2 applications where App2 is accessible when we click on a link in App1.
Each time this link is clicked, a new browser tab is opened containing App2.

Now I have a requirement where upon logout of App1, all the instances (tabs) opened for App2 should be closed.

I tried capturing window objects of App2. And thought of using `winObj.close()` to close each one of them with a loop. But the problem is that how and where can I capture window Objects ? (I need to get those objects when user clicks on logout).

I tried in cookie and localStorage by using
`localStorage.setItem('app2Window', JSON.stringify(window))`
but JSON.stringify(window) gives me following error:

*Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'Window'
--- property 'window' closes the circle
at JSON.stringify ()
at :1:41*

Any help/pointers towards this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you need setup a communication between tabs with [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @vanowm ..
```postMessage()``` is a way to communicate and thats 1 part of the solution, which I get it.
But what I am scratching my head on is that where do i save the window handler objects?
e.g. I opened multiple App2 instances. Now I navigated to many different pages and then decided to logout. Now as soon as I logout, i should have the control of all the window objects which were created earlier so that I can either close them or post the message to them.
I hope I am clear this time.

Comment: As long as your App1 stays in memory, the window handlers of opened app2 can stay in memory too, like in an array or `Map()` or whatever list you'd prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the BroadcastChannel is what you're looking for:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API
- https://developer.chrome.com/blog/broadcastchannel/
  it's main purpose is for one-to-many communication between scripts on the same origin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But for me, both App1 and App2 are on different domains. Also I need a solution in native JS as my project is in Java, but I am redirecting to App2 and closing the tabs from JS

Comment: Hm, this sounds a bit more complex. Can you try this library https://github.com/wingify/across-tabs ? The diagrams describe your use case, where one parent tab open children tabs and then closes them on certain event. I didn't try it myself, but I'm not sure what other option can work here.

Comment: The real ask is where should I save the window objects and how? so that whenever i wish I can either close them or send a message to them using window.postMessage()

Comment: you cannot save the full window object somewhere on the client side. Main reason - it points to itself `window.window == window`, that's why you got this error when trying to serialise it. But even if you were able to serialise it - the functions are not serialisable, so "close" method will be stored as undefined.

Comment: Thanks Petro. I could save window object in redis cache when the same requirement was there for react project. But i cant do this on plain JS (which is used in Java project). any workaround for this ?

Comment: Why are you keep insisting on "storing" it somewhere? what's wrong with a plain old trusted array or an object? Also, Java is different than javascript